# Why does my image change after writing it as a PNG?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide, image-segmentation

I have done some pre-processing on my images; as you can see the image in the MATLAB environment is like this:

[image]

But after saving it by the following command, it becomes like the image below:

```
data=Vol(:,:,ix);
imwrite(uint8(data),outfile,'png','BitDepth',8);
```

[image]

Could you please help me with this? How can I save with the same intensities?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the function wrong

```
imwrite(uint8(data),outfile,'png','BitDepth',8);
```

I believe that if you give the for mat as `'png'` you also need to give the map. Or else, make outfile have the extension already. Additionally, your image may not be `uint8` range, thus you can loose information. Better use `im2uint8`

```
imwrite(im2uint8(data),outfile,'BitDepth',8); %assuming outfile='something.png'
```